# For Loop insert number in Python

Tags: python, loops

How can I insert numbers in loop.

Example

```
for num in range(1, 17):
   print(num)
   arr[:,:,num] = ds.sample(num)
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'sample'

but what I want is:

```
arr[:, :, 1]  = ds.sample1
```

What should I wright in place of num, so that it became sample1

Comment: There is "getattr" to retrieve attributes by string.

Comment: You can't make new variable names dynamically like that. It is hard to recommend a good solution without knowing what `ds` is.

Comment: "but what I want is" No, you don't. You want all those values to be inside a list in the first place, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really tell us what `ds` is, but if `ds` were to be a Pandas `DataFrame`, then maybe you could do something like:

```py
for i,sample in enumerate(ds):
    some_array[i] = ds[sample].values
```

if `ds` were to be a list of samples, then you could do:

```py
for i,sample in enumerate(ds):
    some_array[i] = sample
```

Granted, if `ds` is a `DataFrame`, it's very likely you shouldn't use a for-loop to convert it to a numpy array in your desired format (`some_array = ds.to_numpy()` might be what you want). If `ds` were a list, you could just do something like `some_array = np.array(ds)`.

Comment: ds is xarray.Dataset and It have sample1 to sample17 variable. I tried both but I am getting error for first suggestion is  IndexError: index 17 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 17 and after using second suggestion I am getting error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'sample0'